# Liaison dans « tout oublier »

Tags: liaisons

Dans la phrase

« Il faut tout oublier,  »

est-ce-que la liaison est obligatoire, ou non ? Si non, c'est très formel l'utiliser, ou c'est seulement un peu formel ?

Comment: La liaison du **t** avec le **o** est obligatoire dans « tout oublier ».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En règle générale, la liaison est obligatoire lorsque *tout* est un déterminant ou un adverbe précédant un nom ou un adjectif, mais pas lorsque c'est un pronom.

> Tout oubli sera pénalisé. [obligatoire]
> Signaler tout effet indésirable. [obligatoire]
> Il en est resté tout ébahi. [obligatoire]
>
> On (ne) peut pas tout avoir. [facultatif — soit je suis formel et je mets *ne* et je fais la liaison, soit je suis informel et je ne fais ni l'un ni l'autre]

Je ne vois pas de règle qui imposerait de liaison dans « il faut tout oublier ». Le hiatus si on ne fait pas la liaison me semble néanmoins étrange. Pourtant le double son [u.u] n'est pas exclu en français, par exemple je ne ferais pas de liaison dans la vie de tous les jours dans « partout où j'ai regardé ».

Je pense qu'on a tendance à faire plus la liaison avec *tout* par habitude de la faire quand il est déterminant. Ici, même si elle n'est pas strictement obligatoire, on la ferait en général même en situation informelle.

Comment: Sans réfléchir je fais tjs la liaison dans "il faut tout oublier" mais jamais dans "partout où j'ai regardé". Pourquoi ? L'un sonne bien mais pas l'autre.